# Stevia AutoLayout Library: Excess Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've started using the really cool new IOS Swift AutoLayout library: [Stevia](https://github.com/s4cha/Stevia) for the same reasons the project was started. However, I have been having problems with excess constraints.

In the following example I center 2 views with fixed width and height and align them vertically. However, when I try this with Stevia using either the visual format or the chainable API (2nd code block below), I get conflicts

```
    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    // width
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[givenTF(300)]",
        options:[], metrics:nil, views:["givenTF":givenTF])
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[familyTF(300)]",
        options:[], metrics:nil, views:["familyTF":familyTF])

    // center
    constraints += [NSLayoutConstraint(item: givenTF, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)]

    // vertical alignment
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-(70)-[givenTF(50)]-(2)-[familyTF(50)]",
        options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil,
        views: ["givenTF":givenTF, "familyTF":familyTF])

    self.view.addConstraints(constraints)
```

The Stevia visual format I tried:

```
    self.view.layout([
        70,
        givenTF.centerHorizontally().size(300) ~ 50,
        2,
        familyTF.centerHorizontally().size(300) ~ 50
    ])
    // Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
```

as well as the Chainable API:

```
    givenTF.top(70).centerHorizontally().size(300).height(50)
    familyTF.top(122).centerHorizontally().size(300).height(50)
    // Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
```

I have tried changing the order the methods are called in as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After debugging the conflicting constraints I realized that I had two height constraints. After looking through the Stevia source code I realized that the correct method for setting width is not size() but width(). Size sets both the height and the width.

```
 self.view.layout([
     70,
     givenTF.centerHorizontally().width(300) ~ 50,
     2,
     familyTF.centerHorizontally().width(300) ~ 50
 ])
```

If only autocomplete didn't always crap out on me in XCode 7, I might have realized this sooner...

Comment: Are you still using Stevia? Still your favorite layout API?

Comment: I haven't used it in a while? What layout APIs do you use?